# KinematicBody won't move along z-axis (Godot)

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm beginning a new project and just started coding the movement script. I'm using the same old method I use every time but for some reason I cant move forward and backwards(z-axis). This is odd because left and right (x-axis) uses functionally identical code and works fine. Here's my code:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    
    velocity += gravity * delta
    
    _get_input()
    
    
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)


func _get_input():
    
    var vy = velocity.y
    
    var dir = Vector3()
    
    velocity = Vector3()
    
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("forward"):
        dir += -transform.basis.z * speed

    if Input.is_action_pressed("back"):
        dir += transform.basis.z * speed
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        dir += -transform.basis.x * speed
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        dir += transform.basis.x * speed
        
    
    

    velocity.y = vy
    velocity.x = dir.x
    velocity.z = dir.z
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The first reason that comes to mind for why this could not work is the input map. Double check if `"forward"` and `"back"` is right. The other thing I can think of is that when the `z` of the basis is aligned with the y axis, it won't apply. Edit: try adding break points in the `"forward"` and `"back"` to see if it enters there. Also have it print `dir` to see what values it is getting, that should help you figure out what the issue is.

Comment: @Theraot The input map is ok but I printed `dir` in the console and whenever I go forward or backwards it only changes the y-value. What do you mean about the z axis aligning with y.

Comment: What is the value of `transform.basis.z`? Is it `(0, something, 0)`? That would be the case if the object is rotated in such way that its local z axis is aligned with the y axis of the parent. And if that is the cases then adding or subtracting `transform.basis.z` into `dir` only changes `dir.y` which you do not use.

Comment: @Theraot Yes that's exactly whats happening. I rotated my character 90 degrees to have him straight up. Even when I reset the rotation and set all tranform values to 0, the problem still persists. This is beyond me.

Comment: Sounds like you have a model that imported in the wrong orientation. If that is the case, apply the transform to correct it to the `MeshInstance`s (you may have to update the colliders too), and reset the transform of the `KinematicBody`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach based on the following assumptions:

- Gravity direction is global.
- The `KinematicBody` can be oriented freely.
- The controls follow that orientation.
- The speed is global (this would only matter if the physics body is scaled, and you should avoid scaling physic bodies anyway).

We start by building a local direction vector:

```
    var local_direction:Vector3
    if Input.is_action_pressed("forward"):
        local_direction += Vector3.FORWARD

    if Input.is_action_pressed("back"):
        local_direction += Vector3.BACK
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        local_direction += Vector3.LEFT
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        local_direction += Vector3.RIGHT
```

In fact, we can do that better than that:

```
    var local_direction := Vector3(
        Input.get_action_strength("right") - Input.get_action_strength("left"),
        0.0,
        Input.get_action_strength("back") - Input.get_action_strength("forward")
    )
```

Then we transform it with the global basis:

```
var direction := global_transform.basis.xform(local_direction).normalize()
```

Then we can get rid of the `y` component:

```
direction.y = 0.0
```

And scale it, so it is a velocity:

```
velocity = direction * speed
```

And, of course, you would set the `y` component of the velocity we have, because the gravity computation handles care of that:

```
    var v_velocity := velocity.y
    velocity = direction * speed
    velocity.y = v_velocity
```

All toghether:

```
    var local_direction := Vector3(
        Input.get_action_strength("right") - Input.get_action_strength("left"),
        0.0,
        Input.get_action_strength("back") - Input.get_action_strength("forward")
    )
    var direction := global_transform.basis.xform(local_direction)
    direction.y = 0.0
    var v_velocity := velocity.y
    velocity = direction * speed
    velocity.y = v_velocity
```